# Tag Synonym Request: [timetracking] -> [time-tracking]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are two tags [time-tracking](/questions/tagged/time-tracking) and [timetracking](/questions/tagged/timetracking) on Stackoverflow. I suggest to make [timetracking](/questions/tagged/timetracking) a synonym for [time-tracking](/questions/tagged/time-tracking)

Comment: Just get 5 up votes in the time tracking tag, and suggest it yourself!

Comment: @Richard: This tag currently has only 5 users who could theoretically vote on this synonym proposal - meaning that it will take years to get approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the questions from [timetracking](/questions/tagged/timetracking) have been merged into [time-tracking](/questions/tagged/time-tracking) and the tag will die within 24 hours. A synonym is not needed (it's useless) because typing "timetracking" or "time-tracking" will yield the exact same results.